# How to select a playwright project for you tests inside vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, e2e-testing, playwright

I have a Playwright config file with 2 project, one for development and one for ci:

```
projects: [
{
  ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
  name: 'Default',
  retries: 2,
  use: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000'
  },
},
{
  ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
  name: 'CI',
  retries: 0,
  use: {
    baseURL: 'https://my-dev-url/app'
  },
},
```

Then when I start the test inside vscode

[image]

it always uses the `CI` project. The weird thing is, when I swap the projects it doesn't matter. So my question, how can I define the project to use in vscode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, by default, it should select the first project as a run profile. However, you can change the project inside the Test Explorer tab.

Also, please make sure that you have the latest playwright and plugin versions as well.

[image: change project profile]

Comment: I completely missed that dropdown. For a second I thought that I didn't have that dropdown, but that was because I only had one project in my current config :) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: That’s all right :)